# Higher, greater or bigger distance?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following is most correct?

> The distance of the shortest path must not be higher than 10km.
>   The distance of the shortest path must not be greater than 10km.
>   The distance of the shortest path must not be bigger than 10km.

Or is there an even better word?

Comment: 'Distance' should be replaced by 'length' for idiomatic English, but that doesn't change any of the answers.

Comment: The shortest path must not be longer than 10km.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As height is not being mentioned here, but rather distance on a horizontal scale, "higher" would be inappropriate.

"Bigger" refers to size, not magnitude, and therefore, in this case, is also inappropriate.  It's inappropriate because "distance" cannot be measured in size, but in magnitude. "Great length" not "big length".

That leaves, "greater" which is correct.

A better phrasing could be:

> The distance of the shortest path must not be more than 10km.

Comment: what is size if not magnitude?

Comment: Size, as in amount. Length is not an amount, but a measure of dimensions

Comment: I disagree with your definitions. However I agree that *greater* is the better word to use.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=greater+distance%2C+further+distance%2C+bigger+distance%2C+higher+distance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), "greater distance" is the most common:

[image]

Next after this is "further", as in "I ran further than he did". You could also say:

> The distance of the shortest path must not be further than 10km.

However, I would suggest using "greater" as it seems to fit the context better.

Comment: "greater distance" suggests that something is farther away. I don't think the path is far away, it is long or short. The _end_ of the path might be far away. So I wouldn't say "The distance of X must not be further than....". "Distance of" isn't idomatic, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree that "greater than" is correct, I'm not sure about the rest of the sentence. Two places have a distance between them, but does a path have a distance? I don't think it does.

> The length of the shortest path must not be greater than 10km

or even

> The shortest path must not be longer than 10km

Comment: +1 For "The shortest path must not be longer than 10km." I feel that this is the most accurate, appropriate way to express the idea in the question. Or alternatively, "The shortest path must be no longer than 10km."

Comment: +1 for "paths don't have distance".

Comment: "must not be over 10km" even simpler

Answer (score 2):

> The distance of the shortest path must not be greater than 10km.

This one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Other workable constructions:

- The length of the shortest path must not be *above* 10 km.
- The length of the shortest path must not *exceed* 10 km.

With the latter, you can even omit “the length”, as it’s implied:

- The shortest path must not *exceed* 10 km.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you go for **longer** distance? E.g. the distance is much **longer** than 2 miles.