# Difference between "size" and "magnitude"

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Following the comments to this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39461/higher-greater-or-bigger-distance/39463#39463) to another question, what is the difference between *size* and *magnitude*?

I know there's a difference, but can someone put it in a nutshell for me?

Comment: What is it that you find confusing after reading the definitions?

Comment: I can't state it out in a logical way. I can't state their difference. Like what Matt Ellen said, he disagreed with what I said

Comment: I'm not sure the comments to the answer you're referencing use *size* and *magnitude* correctly, although they certainly serve to convey the intended meaning.

Comment: I don't think this one will fit in a nutshell. Anything you say about either definition can be contradicted by a counterexample or a counter-definition from a particular discipline (astronomy, mathematics, etc.)

Comment: In science, magnitude also means the amount (or absolute value) of something without considering the direction. So a force of 10 N at an angle of 30° has a magnitude of 10 N.

Comment: "Magnitude" sounds more majestic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, *size* connotes physical dimensions while *magnitude* connotes either a numerical measure (particularly a non-linear one) of any sort of amount or metaphorical size.

"What size is that screw?" (Physical dimensions)

"A problem of immense magnitude" (Metaphorical size)

You can also use *size* to mean metaphorical size, but you usually can't use *magnitude* alone to mean physical size. (Nobody would say "What's your sneaker magnitude?")

Comment: +1: I think the suggestion that `size` is primarily used for physical dimensions while `magnitude` is more generally applicable sounds right.

Comment: I'm certainly going to be asking people for their "sneaker magnitude" after reading this.

Answer (score 1):

The difference/usage exists mainly in natural sciences (physics)

- size: has nearly always a linear scale, if the size gets bigger, it also means higher positive absolute values of the according physical quantitiy (temperature, volume,...)
- magnitude: has more the meaning "order of magnitude" and is often used esp. for logarithmic scales when linear scales are too unhandy and typical order of magnitudes like *milli, nano, ...* fail for practical use (e.g. *magnitude of earthquakes, apparent magnitude* in astronomy (here the unity is *mag* but a more negative *mag* value means a brighter astronomical object! so its counter intuitive to typical physical quantities.)).

Answer (score 1):

"Magnitude" connotes the quality of being big, whereas "size" is merely a measure of how big something is.

Comment: Sounds very explanatory for me.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, magnitude, together with direction, describes a vector.  For instance, an object is said to have a velocity if it travels in a particular direction (say, "Northeast") at a particular rate (say, "30 knots").  The magnitude of velocity is speed, which does not imply a direction.  Only values with a direction are said to have magnitude in this way; scalar values, such as an object's mass, or physical dimension (size) is never described in this way.  Of course, there are many other ways that the word 'magnitude' is used

Answer (score -1):

Both have technical meanings - e.g. `size` in fashion, `magnitude` in cosmology. However, in general usage the difference is really a matter of register.